# Clear eclipse configuration after each test case file runs in SWTBot testing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I have some 5testcase(SWTBot test) classes in a package in project, all work properly separately, but if i run them all at once then some widget may be left open and remaining files fail. So how to clear the eclipse configuration after each testcase file?
May be write a line at end that will clear configurtion? I dont want to relunch eclipse after each file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automated test must be self-contained, and it's the responsibility of a TestCase to finish properly and close the remaining files/streams/dialogs.
So you should add some @After methods which close the dialogs after the test use this, so next test will start and a clean application independently of previous test.